# Find out if method was called via trait?

Tags: php, traits

In PHP, how do I find out if a class method was called via a method inherited from a trait?

Say I have a class `myClass` that uses the `Psr\Log\LoggerTrait` (see: [PSR-3](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md)). I need to be able to find out if the method `myClass::log()` was called via a method from the `Psr\Log\LoggerTrait`, for example `LoggerTrait::debug()`, or if it was called directly from outside `myClass`.

All the methods are non-static.

This is related to a debugging package. I'm not trying to alter behavior based on the caller, I just need to be able to pass that information forward. And to be more precise, I need just the entry point, ie. just the last call outside of my package.

I'm looking at `debug_backtrace()` but it doesn't seem to offer any direct solutions. Is there some rational way of doing this?

Here's some code:

```
<?php

class myClass
{
    use Psr\Log\LoggerTrait;

    public function log($level, $message, array $context = array())
    {
        if (called_via_trait) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}

$myObject = new myClass;

$myObject->log('debug', 'This is a direct call');
$myObject->debug('This is a call via a trait method');
```

Comment: Why do you need to know who is calling your class? I would consider finding an alternative approach.

Comment: @JohnCartwright I don't need to know **who** was calling it as such, just whether the call is coming from inside or outside of my package. I'm dealing with debugging information here, so it's very much relevant.

Comment: Well, to determine this, you need to determine who called you. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by package exactly either. Regardless, to ensure I'm not overlooking something, why aren't you supporting multiple interfaces for different behavior? Have code inside your package call a different interface than external consumers. I have a feeling I'm not understanding what your trying to accomplish though.

Comment: @JohnCartwright By package I mean a [software package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_package), which can be acquired and used in another project as a contained, well, package. Having a public `log()` is mandatory since I'm using the `LoggerTrait`. I'm not trying to find the caller to alter behavior, but to keep it static: the package deals with debugging, so no matter which way the `log()` method was called, it should be able to find out where the call originated from.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [get_called_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) to determine the class that called it.

```
trait Test {
   public function doTest() {
       echo get_called_class() . "\n";
   }
}

class Some {
    use Test;

    public function myFunc() {
        $this->doTest();
    }
}

$some = new Some();
$some->myFunc(); // Outputs "Some" since Some uses Test
```

So in your case, inside your class, you could do something like

```
function test() {
    if(get_called_class() == 'myClass') {
        // You're in the myClass class
    } else {
        // You're not in the myClass class
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry about the ambiguity in the question, I forgot to mention that the methods are non-static. I added the info to the question. I always wondered why the standard was to use the dreaded "Paamayim Nekudotayim" in docs, even for non-static methods. This is what happens... Anyway, thanks for the answer, I'm upvoting since it answers what might have been the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use `debug_backtrace();` Please follow my example:

```
namespace Psr\Log; 
class LoggerTrait{
     public static function debug(){
        return myClass::log();
    }
}
class myClass{

     public static function log(){
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        if(isset($trace[1])){
            echo'<br />Called by  <b>'.$trace[1]['class'].'</b>. ';
        } else {
            echo'<br />Called by  <b>'.$trace[0]['class'].'</b>. ';
        }
        if(isset($trace[1]['class']) && $trace[1]['class']!=get_class()){
            echo'Called outside';
        } else {
            echo'Called inside';
        }
        //return get_class();
    }
}


trait ExampleTrait {
    public function doSay() {
        echo LoggerTrait::debug();
        echo myClass::log();
    }
}
echo LoggerTrait::debug();
echo myClass::log();
echo ExampleTrait::doSay();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem here is that `get_class()` will always be `myClass`, so this wont work.